# Derive the convexity adjustment for inflation YoY swap with unconventional payoff

Tags: swaps, hullwhite, convexity, inflation, brownian

I'm trying to solve for the convexity adjustment for an inflation YoY swap with unconventional payoff, where $I_i$ is CPI at time i:

$Notional * ([I_i/I_{i-1}]^{Day Count Fraction} - 1)$

In the normal case, the payoff is: $Notional * Day Count Fraction * (I_i/I_{i-1} - 1)$
And we can show using the Jarrow-Yildirim model that the PV is  as follows:

[image]

with convexity adjustment  (e^D_i (t) ),
where
[image]

However I am struggling with the payoff *raised* to the day count fraction instead of *multiplied* by day count fraction. How can I deal with this raised power in the convexity adjustment derivation?

Comment: This is unnatural.  Are you sure this is the payoff ?

Comment: yes the payoff is accurate.

Comment: What is the date of the payoff ?  If the yoy swap is annual pay , then day count fraction is 1, so the convention is the same.

Comment: the coupons pay quarterly, so the day count fraction for each coupon payment T_i will be from [T_i, 3m]